# SVN - Cancelled Import

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I recently attempted an import into SVN (via tortiesSVN).  It was a rather large ASP.Net project so I left it unattended.  However, when returning to my pc 10 minutes later it was still importing and I realised that I was accidentally importing the whole parent folder which contains all my ASP.Net projects.

I clicked the cancel button and the process stopped, however Im now worried that my SVN Repository is bloated with these files.  The Repository sites on my external VPS server which has a limited amount of disk space.  Is there a way of clearing these files out or at least inspecting what files  are there?

Thanks for any assistance someone can give me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

svn operations are atomic. Either they succeed fully, or they fail completely. Since you canceled the import, the import did not happen at all. It did not succeed just partially because then an import would not be atomic.

So you're fine: the import didn't happen at all. There are no files left on the server (except for maybe some log files).